# Map from a plane to a grid

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Define a point P in $[-1, 1] \times [-1,1]$. We want to map it to a grid $[0, x] \times [0,y]$. Something like pixels in the screen. In other words, find the pixels which corresponds to a point with given coordinates in the plane. What would be an appropriate transformation matrix?

Comment: MathJax tip `\times` produces $\times$.

Comment: There will not be a transformation *matrix*, as such a map cannot be linear (remember, linear transformations map $(0, 0)$ to $(0, 0)$). Instead, we will have an affine transformation, which means that you'll be able to express $$T(x, y) = A\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + b$$ for some $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ and column vector $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say the grid is $[0, w] \times [0, h]$.

Then what you probably want is

$$
(x, y) \mapsto \left( (w+1)\frac{x+1}{2} - \frac12,  (h+1)\frac{y+1}{2} - \frac12 \right)
$$
where each of the terms on the right should be rounded off if you want integer coordinates. Other folks will tell you to use
$$
(x, y) \mapsto \left( w\frac{x+1}{2} ,  h\frac{y+1}{2} \right)
$$
(again rounding), but it almost certainly won't get you what you want. Whether it'll be different enough to notice is another matter.

Assuming you represent your input points as $\pmatrix {x\\y\\1}$ (i.e., using homogeneous coordinates), the matrix for this transformation would be
$$
\pmatrix{
\frac{w+1}{2}& 0& -\frac{w}{2}\\
0 &\frac{ h+1}{2} & -\frac{h}{2}
}
$$
if I haven't screwed up the algebra.

Comment: That seems to work. Could you elaborate how did you find the mapping? I mean, where this x+1 and w+1 come from. Also, where do you use the original plane ( which is [-1, 1]x[-1, 1] ). Also, thank you for the fast response!

Comment: Um...I sorta did elaborate on this. I co-wrote a 1350 page book called "Computer Graphics, Principles and Practice, 3rd edition." The short answer: I didn't so much find the mapping as remember it from the 50 or so other times I've needed it during my career. In a little more detail, I composed a translation to move (-1,1) to the origin, a "Scale" by 0.5 (w+1, h+1) to make the square into a big enough rectangle, and a translation by (-0.5, -0.5) to make the outermost four pixel-centers correspond to the original corners of the square. Then I multiplied the corresponding matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much!